# Remove node with largest priority value

Tags: java

I have LinkedList full of nodes, each of which has a number. I am having an issue however creating a method that is supposed to remove the node that has the highest priority number in the list. Here's what I have so far...

```
public E removeHigh() throws ListException{
   Node<E> previous = head;
```

Answer (score 0):

`highestPriority` is of type `Node`.

And the return type of your method is `E`.

You will need to make sure that you return `Node` which has the highest priority.

Comment: @D.Fowler The logic is faulty. In the first pass you will need to find the node with highest priority. Then in the second pass go to that node and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You get a "OrderedList.Node cannot be converted to E" exception because the method signature requires the return type to be `E`, but what you actually return is `highestPriority` of type `Node<E>`. Either change the return to `highestPriority.priority` or change the signature.

If you want to remove an item of a LinkedList, you need to restructure the items that link to it. In this case, you would want `previous.next` to point to the item after `current`, or `null` if it's the last item.

Comment: You need to do the removal after the loop. Save the previous and next node of highestPriority and then after the while loop assign next to previous.next.

Comment: Assuming you saved the references of the items previous and next to `highestPriority` – in the same place you set `highestPriority = current`, of course – you can now just write `previous.next = next`. This way, `previous.next` does not point to `highestPriority` anymore but to `next` instead.

Comment: You need two new variables. Let's call them `highestPriorityPrev` and `highestPriorityNext`. You set them to the previous and next items of `highestPriority` respectively, _only_ in the same block where you set `highestPriority`. Then you do `highestPriorityPrev.next = highestPriorityNext` after the while loop.

Comment: Okay so I updated the problem again. Does that solve it?

Comment: You should use curly brackets here since there's more than one statement in your if bodies. Then it should work. Also, instead of editing the original code, put the update in a new paragraph so that other readers still know what the original code looked like.